# p:dataTable never refreshes after a delete, update or insert

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Well, I have a p:dialog that inserts a new Entity, but after this entity is saved into database the p:dataTable remains the same, the new row doesn't appear.

Look at my p:dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form id="formCadastrar">

            <p:dialog width="900px" height="500px" header="Cadastrar Dentista"
                widgetVar="dialogCadastrar" modal="true">

                <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">

                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" value="Salvar"
                        actionListener="#{dentistaMB.salvar}"
                        update=":formDentistas:dataTableDentistas" />

                    <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" icon="ui-icon-close"
                        onclick="confirmCancelar.show()" type="button" />

                </p:panelGrid>


                <p:panelGrid id="panelGridCadastar" styleClass="semBorda"
                    columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Nome: *" />
                    <p:inputText id="nome"
                        value="#{dentistaMB.dentista.pessoaFisica.nome}" size="40"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="O Nome do Dentista é obrigatório">
                    </p:inputText>

                    <h:outputText value="CRO *" />
                    <p:inputText id="cro" value="#{dentistaMB.dentista.cro}" size="10"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="O Número do CRO é obrigatório" />
                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" value="Salvar"
                        actionListener="#{dentistaMB.salvar}"
                        update=":formDentistas:dataTableDentistas" />

                    <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" icon="ui-icon-close"
                        onclick="confirmCancelar.show()" />
                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:confirmDialog id="confirmCancelar" message="Deseja cancelar ?"
                    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" header="Cancelar"
                    severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmCancelar" appendToBody="true">
                    <p:commandButton value="Sim" oncomplete="confirmCancelar.hide()"
                        actionListener="#{dentistaMB.cancelar}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Não" onclick="confirmCancelar.hide()"
                        type="button" />
                </p:confirmDialog>

            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>


</h:body>
</html>
```

And look at my p:dataTable

```
<h:form id="formDentistas">

                <p:growl autoUpdate="true" id="growlmessages" />

                <p:dataTable rowKey="#{dentista.id}" var="dentista" value="#{dentistaMB.dentistas}"
                    paginator="true" emptyMessage="Não foi encontrado nenhum registro"
                    rows="10" id="dataTableDentistas"
                    selection="#{dentistaMB.selectedDentista}" selectionMode="single">

                    <f:facet name="header">Lista de Dentistas</f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="nome" filterBy="nome" id="nome"
                        width="200px">
                    #{dentista.pessoaFisica.nome}
                </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Data Nascimento" sortBy="dataNascimento"
                        filterBy="dataNascimento" id="dataNascimento" width="60px">
                    #{dentista.pessoaFisica.dataNascimento}
                </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="CRO" sortBy="cro" filterBy="cro" id="cro"
                        width="60px">
                    #{dentista.cro}
                </p:column>


                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <div class="align_text_left">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" value="Novo" id="cadastrar"
                            oncomplete="dialogCadastrar.show()" />

                        <p:column headerText="Ações" style="width:50px;">
                            <p:commandButton value="Alterar" icon="ui-icon-pencil" />

                            <p:commandButton value="Remover" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                                action="#{dentistaMB.deletar}"
                                update=":formDentistas:dataTableDentistas" />
                        </p:column>
                        </div>
                    </f:facet>

                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

So, what's the correct form to update the p:dataTable after a change in an entity? This example above is about an *insert*, but *remove* doesn't work either. I used the following code:

```
<p:commandButton value="Remover" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                                action="#{dentistaMB.deletar}"
                                update=":formDentistas:dataTableDentistas" />
```

Comment: Make sure your managed bean is `@ViewScoped` and that you retrieve the data from database in `@PostConstruct` method. Also, do not forget to retrieve the data again after the insert/update/delete operation.

Comment: My error, i forget to lookup again the list of "dentistas" then the dataTable is never updated. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

in your dialog you must add an ajax event to fire update of form like:

```
            <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{dentistaMB.load}"
            update=":formDentistas" immediate="true" global="false" />
```

this will allow you to reload your table feed lists.

in your load method you need to update (refetch data from db) dentistas list. If you are using filtering do not forget to update your filtering list as well.

In managedbean load function you can use:

```
    public void load(){
        dentistas.clear();
        filteredDentistas.clear();
        dentistas.addAll(getDentistService().getDentists());
        filteredDentistas.addAll(getDentistService().getDentists());
}
```